# angluarjs module DI dosen't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

why I can't inject this dep? it throws a error:"helper provider doesn't find"

code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test',[])
.factory('helper',function () {
    return {
        luckier: function () {
            alert('you');
        }
    };
});
var cardpage = angular.module('card',['test'],function (helper,$interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
var initModel = function () {
    return {
        cardName: 'x', 
        cardColor: 'x', 
        cardBg: 'x',
        cardLogo: 'x',
        cardFontColor: 'x',
        cardChargetPass: 'x'
    };  
};

cardpage.controller('cardCtrl',function (helper,$scope) {
    $scope.model = initModel();
    helper.luckier();
    $scope.color = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a function to the `angular.module` . You may be looking for a config function, or run block. However you cannot inject anything but providers and constants into your config block.. You might try:

```
angular.module('card',['test']).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
})
.run(function(helper){
   //first place a factory,or service can be injected.       
});
```

Also see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) and [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#config)